# sed -i '/$(command 1)/$(command 2)/' myHtmlFile ? Inline editing with sed and awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I'm writing a shell script that builds and edits an html file whose main content is basically clamscan's (ClamAV) output. 
So, the script's mission is : translating the output, removing unhelpful stuff, adding html tags and so on.
Though, i'm stuck with the last modification i want.

One part of the edited output from clamscan looks like this :

```
/path/to/infected-file: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
/path/to/infected-zipfile!(1)ZIP:eicar.com: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
/path/to/infected-zipfilewithinzipfile!ZIP:eicar_com.zip!(2)ZIP:eicar.com: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
```

I want to shrink those long lines. Something like this would be the best :

```
infected-file: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
infected-zipfile: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
infected-zipfilewithinzipfile: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
```

But i'd already be happy to just remove the path to the infected file.

Since it seemed easy to get some results with awk and i used sed for all previous editing, I thought my best option was going with something like :
`sed -i 's/<awk command 1>/<awk command 2>/' myHtmlFile`

Unfortunately i spent a few hours turning this in various way with no luck.

There seems to be syntax issues with things like :

```
sed "s#$(awk -F': ' '{print $1}' testfile)#$(awk -F': ' '{print $1}' testfile | awk -F'\' '{print $NF}')#" testfile
```

whether i use single or double quotes, whether i try to concatenate sed strings or try to escape various chars depending on the chosen syntax.

I also though about loops (so that i could make sed work with vars containing awk results) but i'm unsure how to manage a loop for this kind of inline editing.
It could probably be solved with a powerful regex, but i'm quite bad at it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's#[^:]+/([^:!]+).*: #\1: #' file
infected-file: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
infected-zipfile: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
infected-zipfilewithinzipfile: Eicar-Test-Signature<span class="mep-subhead-warning"> FOUND</span>
```

The above regexp does this:

1. `[^:]+/` - consumes a leading string that contains no colons and ends in `/`, e.g. `/path/to/`
2. `([^:!]+)` - saves the subsequent string that contains no colons or exclamation marks in a capture group, e.g. `infected-zipfile`
3. `.*:` - consumes the subsequent string leading up to a colon followed by a blank char, e.g. `!(1)ZIP:eicar.com:`.

and then the replacement does this:

1. `\1` - print the string saved into capture group 1 in step 2 above
2. `:` - print a colon followed by a blank char (I could have used a capture group for this too)

Comment: Perfect. I quite don't understand the regex tho ^^'

Comment: OK, I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
So, to have inline editing, what i inserted in my bash script is :

`sed -i -r '/mep-subhead-warning/s#[^:]+/([^:!]+).*: #\1: #' myHtmlFile`

Answer (score 0):

Ed Morton has already explained how to do this with a single regex substitution (i.e. the right way); I'll explain what's wrong with the original approach, and show how to do it with a shell loop (i.e. the wrong way).

The problem with the combined sed+awk+awk approach is that you need them to operate line-by-line in lockstep. That is, when sed processes line N of the file, it needs to replace the Nth line of output from the first awk command with the Nth line of output from the second awk pipeline. But the commands don't interrelate that way; the shell runs all of the awk commands, collects their entire output, then feeds that to sed as a single huge (and malformed) substitute expression. Given your sample data (and assuming the last awk command should have `-f '/'` instead of `-f '\'`), it would do essentially this:

```
sed 's#/path/to/infected-file
/path/to/infected-zipfile!(1)ZIP:eicar.com
/path/to/infected-zipfilewithinzipfile!ZIP:eicar_com.zip!(2)ZIP:eicar.com#infected-file
infected-zipfile!(1)ZIP:eicar.com
infected-zipfilewithinzipfile!ZIP:eicar_com.zip!(2)ZIP:eicar.com#' testfile
```

sed will reject this because of the newlines in the pattern (and replacement string as well). If it weren't for it being rejected, sed would go ahead and try to apply the whole mess to every line separately, but since it's not actually what you wanted that wouldn't work either.

In order to get all of those commands to work line-by-line in lockstep, you'd have to do something like use a shell loop to read and process each line through each of the commands (&pipeline) individually, like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    fullpath=$(echo "$line" | awk -F': ' '{print $1}')
    trimmedpath=$(echo "$line" | awk -F': ' '{print $1}' testfile | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
    echo "$line" | sed "s#$fullpath#$trimmedpath#"
done < testfile
```

You could actually skip the `fullpath` and `trimmedpath` variables, and use the two `$(echo "$line" | awk...)` substitutions directly in the sed command if you wanted. But really, you shouldn't do it this way at all; use Ed's single-regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#^([^/]*/)*([[:alpha:]-]*)([^:]*:)* #\2: #' file
```

This removes any directories, keeps the file name and removes any superfluous characters up to a `:` followed by a space.